# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un botón que se repite múltiples veces?

Tags: php, javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores de un botón que se repite múltiples veces?, tengo una tabla que para editar una fila abre un modal (adjunto imagen), quisiera obtener los valores del boton eliminar para poderlos usar en ajax para posterior borrarlos de la base de datos, el asunto que tengo es que quisiera que esos valores se almacenen en una única variable para pasarlas por parámetros por ajax y usarlos posteriormente en un controlador y en un modelo. Ayuda por favor.

El botón tiene su id unico.

**Imagen donde quiero obtener los valores del boton y ponerlos en una unica variable**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi codigo donde imprimo los datos que recibo del ajax en el modal y posterior dibujar la minitabla donde estan los metros y el precio final**

1.

```
data.post[1].forEach(item => {
                    // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
                    // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
                    let html = `<tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="editarIdPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_OTPloteo}">
                                                <input type="text" name="editarMetrosTotalPloteo[]" class="editarMetrosTotalPloteo form-control"
    value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control editarImporteMetrosPloteo" name="editarImporteMetrosPloteo[]"
    value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="${(item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo)}" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon"
    type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>`;
                    // Agrega fila a la tabla
                    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
                                });
                            /* AGREGAR COLUMNAS A LA MINI TABLA EDITAR OT PLOTEO */             $('#editarAgregarPloteo').on('click', function () {
                    /* OBTENCION DEL VALOR DEL INPUT */
                    let datos = $('#editarMetrosPloteo').val()
                    
                    if (datos != '') {
                        
                        /* PROCESO PARA AUMENTAR LAS FILAS EN LA TABLA PARA AGREGAR METROS */
                        tabla = `<tr>`;
                        tabla += `<td><input type="text" name="editarMetrosTotalPloteo[]" class="editarMetrosTotalPloteo
    form-control" value="${datos}"></td>`;
                        tabla += `<td><input type="text" class="form-control editarImporteMetrosPloteo" name="editarImporteMetrosPloteo[]"
    value="${(datos * 1.25).toFixed(2)}" readonly></td>`;
                        tabla += `<td><a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i
    class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>`;
                        tabla += `</tr>`;
                        
                        /* DIBUJAR LA TABLA EN LA TABLA RESPECTIVA EN EL HTML */
                        $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(tabla);
                        editarCalculosMetrosPloteo()
                        $('#editarAgregarPloteo').val(null);
                        /* FUNCION PARA HACER LOS CALCULOS */
                    }
                    
                    /* LIMPIEZA DEL INPUT DESPUES DE AGREGAR LOS METROS */
                    $('input[name=editarMetrosPloteo]').val('');
                    
                    /* ELIMINACION INDIVIDUAL DE LOS METROS CUANDO LA TABLA YA ESTA CREADA */
                    $(document).on('keyup', '.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo input.editarMetrosTotalPloteo', function () {
                        
                        /* OBTENER EL VALOR DEL INPUT */
                        let metros = $(this).val();
                        // alert(metros)
                        
                        /* CALCULOS */
                        let importe = (metros * 1.25).toFixed(2)
                        
                        /* IMPRESION EN EL INPUT READONLY DE LA COLUMNA DE IMPORTES */
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').children('input').val(importe)
                    })
                                });             $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
                    editarCalculosMetrosPloteo()            })
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: Puedes compartirnos tu código, de esa forma sera mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias @JesusOchoa acabe de adjuntar mi codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actualización:

Dentro de la función que abre el modal defines el arreglo que almacena los valores a borrar, además de incluir `$(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () { ... }`.

Como resultado, cada que se abre un modal se define un arreglo y se crea una función para "escuchar" clics en botones con clase "eliminarMetros".

Solución:

```
// Define el arreglo en contexto global, fuera de cualquier función:
let paraBorrar = [];

// Aquí la función para abrir el modal:
function funcionQueAbreModal(parametros, necesarios) {
    // Vacía el arreglo, sin usar let, ni var:
    paraBorrar = [];
    // Abre el modal
}

// También en contexto global "escucha" clics en botones:
$(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () { ... }
```

**Fin de actualización**

En la respuesta de tu otra pregunta se me pasó por alto que se estaba repitiendo ID para el enlace `id="eliminarMetros"` y deben ser únicos. Las modificaciones:

- Agregar un arreglo donde se almacenarán los ID de elementos a borrar
- Quitar ID *eliminarMetros* y agregar al final de la lista de clases de cada enlace para borrar
- Modificar la función para obtener los enlaces por clase y no por ID
- Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón, para buscar desde ahí idPloteo del elemento a borrar
- Agregar ID a elementos que se van a borrar de la base de datos
- Eliminar la fila

```js
// El arreglo debe definirse en contexto global
// Fuera de ciclos y funciones
let paraBorrar = [];
let data = {
    "respuesta": "success",
    "post": [
        {
            "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
            "ID_Cliente": "3",
            "ID_Documento": "2",
            "Subtotal_OTPloteo": "23.75",
            "Impuesto_OTPloteo": "2.85",
            "Total_OTPloteo": "26.60",
            "NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo": "000140",
            "Serie_OTPloteo": "001",
            "Fecha_OTPloteo": "2020-08-19 21:45:12",
            "Nombre_Cliente": "David Alejandro",
            "Apellido_Cliente": "Paucar Briones",
            "Telefono_Cliente": "0992896820",
            "Nombre_Documento": "Factura",
            "Impuesto_Documento": "12",
            "Cantidad_Documento": "141",
            "Serie_Documento": "001",
            "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
            "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
            "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
        },
        [
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "31",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "7.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "8.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "32",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "9.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "11.25"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

// Recorre los datos
data.post[1].forEach(item => {
    // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
    // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
    let html = `<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="idPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo}">
            <input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly></td>
        <td><a href="#" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon eliminarMetros" type="button"><i class="icon-trash">Borrar</i></a></td>
    </tr>`;
    // Agrega fila a la tabla
    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
});

// Esta función debe estar fuera del ciclo y de cualquier función
$(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () {
    // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // Obtener ID de elemento a eliminar
    let idPloteo = $(tr).find('[name="idPloteo[]"]').val();
    // Agregar a elementos por borrar
    paraBorrar.push(idPloteo);
    // Eliminar fila y volver a calcular
    $(tr).remove();
    // calculosMetrosPloteo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Metros</th>
                                        <th>Precio Final</th>
                                        <th>Acción</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

### Actualización 2

Revisa el funcionamiento del primer ejemplo, no hay duplicados, pero en este sí, ¿por qué?, simplemente porque cada que se ejecuta la función `cargar()` se asigna un nuevo evento a los botones. Espero que ahora sí haya quedado claro.

```js
let data = {
    "respuesta": "success",
    "post": [
        {
            "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
            "ID_Cliente": "3",
            "ID_Documento": "2",
            "Subtotal_OTPloteo": "23.75",
            "Impuesto_OTPloteo": "2.85",
            "Total_OTPloteo": "26.60",
            "NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo": "000140",
            "Serie_OTPloteo": "001",
            "Fecha_OTPloteo": "2020-08-19 21:45:12",
            "Nombre_Cliente": "David Alejandro",
            "Apellido_Cliente": "Paucar Briones",
            "Telefono_Cliente": "0992896820",
            "Nombre_Documento": "Factura",
            "Impuesto_Documento": "12",
            "Cantidad_Documento": "141",
            "Serie_Documento": "001",
            "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
            "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
            "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
        },
        [
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "31",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "7.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "8.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "32",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "9.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "11.25"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
// Simular carga de datos por AJAX
$('#cargar').on('click', cargar);

function cargar() {
    // Esta variable se debe definir en contexto global
    // Fuera de función, para evitar "duplicados"
    let paraBorrar = [];
    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo tbody').empty();
    // Recorre los datos
    data.post[1].forEach(item => {
        // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
        // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
        let html = `<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="idPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo}">
            <input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly></td>
        <td><a href="#" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon eliminarMetros" type="button"><i class="icon-trash">Borrar</i></a></td>
    </tr>`;
        // Agrega fila a la tabla
        $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
    });

    // Esta función debe estar fuera del ciclo y de la función
    // Cuando está dentro, comienza a "duplicar"
    $(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () {
        // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón
        let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // Obtener ID de elemento a eliminar
        let idPloteo = $(tr).find('[name="idPloteo[]"]').val();
        // Agregar a elementos por borrar
        paraBorrar.push(idPloteo);
        // Duplica después de la primera vez
        console.log(paraBorrar);
        // Eliminar fila y volver a calcular
        $(tr).remove();
        // calculosMetrosPloteo();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Metros</th>
               <th>Precio Final</th>
               <th>Acción</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
</table>
<button id="cargar">Cargar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias compa, obtiene el ID pero por ejemplo si elimino las 3 filas necesito obtener todos esos ID's en una sola variable para pasarla al controlador y de ahi mandarla al modelo para que se eliminen de ahi pero ahi esta el problema en el que me hallo :(

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el usuario debe tener el tiempo necesario hasta enviar el formulario para que se eliminen esos datos porque si los hago al instante y el usuario no desea borrarlos o se confundio ahi esta el problema

Comment: te puedo ayudar con mi código que lo tengo en github para que me entiendas mejor como es el resultado que espero ya que por las limitaciones de stack no puedo poner muchas imágenes o videos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112136/discussion-between-david-paucar-and-triby).

Comment: https://vimeo.com/450649688 acabe de adjuntar un video para que puedas observar lo que me sucede

Comment: se siguen duplicando los arrays :( osea los valores ya son propios de cada modal, pero se clona el array, tal cual muestro en el video de vimeo :(

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, revisa el segundo ejemplo, pasa exactamente lo mismo que en tu video y te explico porqué.

Comment: muchas gracias compa me has ayudado mucho y por tu forma la he logrado conseguir, gracias a tu ayuda acabe mi sistema. Espero la pases excelente. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener todos los botones en una lista puedes ponerle una clase a esos botones y recuperarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
 const btnsDeleted= document.getElementsByClassName('btnDelete')
Array.from(btnsDeleted).forEach(item => {
     //lo que desees con item
});
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo con jquery solo modificando la primera linea, el resto deberia ser lo mismo.